# copy a file in java

Tags: java, file-io, copy

I have an XML file looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and
            whipped cream
        </description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</CATALOG>
```

I need to copy this file to another file using `java` programming. the following is my java code to copy the file

```
    try {
        File f1 = new File("source.xml");
        File f2 = new File("destination.xml");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File copied.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out
                .println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e7) {
        System.out.println(e7.getMessage());
    }
```

This code does copy the file, but the problem is that is copies all the content of the source file in one single line, and I need to keep the original structure of the source file. 
Any one have a better idea to copy the file and keep its original structure? 
Thank you

Comment: The above copies the file byte by byte. If the destination file has just one line, it means that the source file only has one as well.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is badly asked, or if it is not clear at all. the thing is that I am learning java and I need more time to figure out how components of a program work. hope any one who gave down-votes understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **BufferedReader** to read line by line using **readLine()** function. Then use BufferedWriter to write the line and then append a new-line charcter using its **newLine()** function.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a new package called [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html), which will simplify things a lot for you. There is also [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29). I advise you to switch to either of these, for performance matters and simpler code.

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
...
String orig ="file.xml";
String dest = "file.xml.bak";
File f = new File (orig);
Path p = f.toPath();
p.copyTo(new File (dest).toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

or

```
import java.file.io;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
....
String orig ="file.xml";
String dest = "file.xml.bak";
File fOrig = new File(orig);
File fDest = new File(dest);
FileUtils.copyFile(fOrig, fDest);
```